# Persian transliteration Java API

Tags: java, api, transliteration, persian

I need transliterate `English` to `Persian` and want to use it in offline mode. Is there any free API that I can use offline ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From English to Persian?

[Google transliterate](http://www.google.com/transliterate/persian)

[api docs (see Java Access)](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/index.html#fonje_snippets)

Cant't seem to find terms if you are using it for commercial reasons

Comment: tnx
i said i want to access such api in offline mode but in google api :
URL url = new URL(
    "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&"
    + "q=Paris%20Hilton&key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&userip=USERS-IP-ADDRESS");

i should make connection to google !
is there any way to access api in offline mode ?

Comment: Doubt it (offline mode), it was just the library/service I could find.

Comment: Google Translate doesn't work from Farsi to English. Don't know about transliterate.

Answer (score 3):

you can also use transliteration service of Parsijoo . the website is http://translate.parsijoo.ir/ 
although it is not offline but is really exact .

Answer (score 1):

if you wana use offline you must download database for this work or create db
i think download babylon dic and convert to db and use it